# How to write increment only once in a file?

Tags: python, append, increment

I read multiple files using for-loop and append output in separate files using the below code. what I am looking for is not to print the line after the `count+=1` (pls see below) every time for each iteration except the final iteration.

```
output.write(file_name + ": The total number of reads with two AB sequences is " +
             str(count) + '\n')
```

Is there a way to print the final `count+=1` only once at the end of the output file based on my code?

```
from Bio import SeqIO

files=['2_.fasta','4_.fasta']

for file_name in files:
    count=0
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
            #some code
            if str(v1) in record.seq and str(v2) in record.seq:
                #some code
                out = "sample" + file_name[:1] + "_two_AB.txt"
                with open(out,'a') as output:
                    output.write(file_name + '\n')
                    output.write(">"+str(record.id) + '\n')
                    count+=1
                    output.write(file_name + ": The total number of reads with two AB sequences is " 
                                 + str(count) + '\n')

output.close()
```

Comment: If i understood your question, you can use a list to save file name, count and record.id. After the FOR, you use the list to write the data with another  FOR.

Comment: Every time you `open(out,'w') as output` anything that might have already been in the file is lost (overwritten).

Comment: thank you for the heads up m@martineau, I actually use ```append``` mode - had forgotten to update it in this question.

Comment: @Ferdinando, Would you please help me with what you suggested with a piece of code?

Comment: @Apex, if you need other things write me and update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps (if i understood your question):

In this code i have used a **list** with a **tuple** to save the information such as **out,file_name, record.id and count**. After i have used this list in a **for** to copy the data, present into list, into corresponding file.

**My code**:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

files=['2_.fasta','4_.fasta']
my_list=[]

for file_name in files:
    count=0
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        for record in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
            #some code
            if str(v1) in record.seq and str(v2) in record.seq:
                #some code
                out = "sample" + file_name[:1] + "_two_AB.txt"
                with open(out,'a') as output:
                    output.write(file_name + '\n')
                    output.write(">"+str(record.id) + '\n')
                    count+=1
                    my_list.append(tuple((out,file_name,str(record.id),count)))
                    #output.write(file_name + ": The total number of reads with two AB sequences is " 
                    #             + str(count) + '\n')

    output.close()
    #Alternative
        #for idx,val enumerate(my_list):
        #    my_out=val[0] # I have out value
        #    my_file_name=[1] # I have the file_name value
        #    my_record=val[2] # I have the record.id value
        #    my_count=val[3] # I have the count value
        #    with open(my_out, 'a') as output:
        #        output.write(my_file_name + '\n')
        #        output.write(">"+ my_record + '\n')
                #output.write(my_file_name + ": The total number of reads with two AB sequences is "+ str(my_count))
        #    output.close()
    
# -1 in this list is the last file
# my_list[-1][0] Here I have out es."sample" + file_name[:1] + "_two_AB.txt"
# my_list[-1][1] Here I have the file_name
# my_list[-1][2] Here I have the record.id
# my_list[-1][3] Here I have the count    
with open(my_list[-1][0], 'a') as output: # my_list[-1][0] is the last file, I have value's "out"
     #output.write(my_list[-1][1] + '\n') #my_list[-1][1] i have my_file_name
     #output.write(">"+ my_list[-1][2] + '\n') #my_record
     output.write(my_list[-1][2] + ": The total number of reads with two AB sequences is "+ str(my_list[-1][3]))
     output.close()
```